# MySQL: Is it safe to lowercase or uppercase regular expression?

Tags: mysql, regex, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I use regular expressions in MySQL on multibyte-encoded (utf-8) data, but I need it to be match case-insensitively. As MySQL has bug (for many years unresolved) that it can't deal properly with matching multibyte-encoded strings case-insensitively, I am trying to simulate the "insensitiveness" by lowercasing the value and the regexp pattern. Is it safe to lowercase regexp pattern such way? I mean, are there any edge cases I forgot?

Could following cause any problems?

```
LOWER('šárKA') = REGEXP LOWER('^Šárka$')
```

Update: I edited the question to be more concrete.

[MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html):

> The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in byte-wise fashion, so **they are not multi-byte safe** and may produce unexpected results with multi-byte character sets. In addition, these operators compare characters by their byte values and **accented characters may not compare as equal even if a given collation treats them as equal**.

It is [their bug filed in 2007](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30241) and unsolved until now. However, I can't just change database to solve this issue. I need MySQL somehow to consider 'Š' equal to 'š', even if it is by hacking it with not-so-elegant solution. Other characters than accented (multi-byte) match well and with no issues.

Comment: in which Langugae. You can use Langugae Specific Methods,

Comment: I updated the question to be more concrete.

Comment: Are you sure a regex is the best tool? I understand the code in the question is just an example, but most of the time you can get by with `LIKE`.

Comment: My application accepts regular expressions as an input from user, so there is no other way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noone actually answered my original question, I made my own research and realized **it is not safe to lowercase or uppercase regular expression** without any other processing. To be precise, it is safe to do this with theoretically pure regular expressions, but their every sane implementation adds some character classes and special directives, which can be vulnerable to case changing:

- Escape sequences like `\n`, `\t`, etc.
- Character classes like `\W` (non-alphanumeric) and `\w` (alphanumeric).
- Character classes like `[.characters.]`, `[=character_class=]`, or `[:character_class:]` (MySQL regular expressions dialect).

Lowercasing or uppercasing `\W` and `\w` could completely change regular expression's meaning. This leads to following conclusion:

- Presented solution is no-go.
- Presented solution is possible, but the regular expression must be lowercased in more sophisticated way than just by using `LOWER` or something similar. It has to be parsed and the case has to be changed carefully.

Answer (score 3):

The `i` option for the Regex will make sure it matches case insensitively.

Example:

```
'^(?i)Foo$' // (?i) will turn on case insensitivity for the rest of the regex
'/^Foo$/i'  // the i options turns off case sensitivity
```

Note that these may not work in your particular Flavour of Regex (which you haven't hinted upon) so make sure you consult your manual for the correct syntax.

Update:

From here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

> REGEXP is not case sensitive, except when used with binary strings.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question to be more concrete. I have no `i` flag available.